# EJabberd 21.04 writing mod_muc_log errors to logs every 3 minutes, even though logging is working

Tags: ejabberd

I am running EJabberd 21.04 on OpenSuse Linux 15.2, and am using the MUC module with room logging.  As far as I can tell, everything is working properly.  Room logs and activity are being written to the room logs.

However, in the ejabberd.log and error.log, the following lines are being written:

```
2021-05-14 15:51:23.000 [error] <0.692.0>@mod_muc_log:handle_cast:130 {{badmatch,{error,enoent}},[{mod_muc_log,add_message_to_log,5,[{file,"src/mod_muc_log.erl"},{line,333}]},{mod_muc_log,handle_cast,2,[{file,"src/mod_muc_log.erl"},{line,129}]},{gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,637}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,711}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}
2021-05-14 15:51:23.001 [error] <0.692.0>@mod_muc_log:handle_cast:130 {{badmatch,{error,enoent}},[{mod_muc_log,add_message_to_log,5,[{file,"src/mod_muc_log.erl"},{line,333}]},{mod_muc_log,handle_cast,2,[{file,"src/mod_muc_log.erl"},{line,129}]},{gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,637}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,711}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}
```

These lines appear every 3 minutes, to the second, whenever the server is in operation.  I don't know what to make of them, and am hoping for guidance on how to make them stop.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code file, and line number, it's file:open that fails with enoent, and looking in http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#open-2

> enoent
>
> The file does not exist.

I'de say that the path where it tries to write the log files does not exist, or doesn't have write permission.